# "Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context." when testing web API

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller

I am trying to test the web API.  I am getting "Unable to create a null constant value of type 'WebAPIStudent.Models.AddressViewModel'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context."

I have read some other similar threads but nothing helps.

Here's my code.

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetAllStudents()
    {
        IList<StudentViewModel> students = null;
        using (var ctx = new StudentDBEntities())
        {
            students = ctx.Students.Include("StudentAddress").Select(s => new StudentViewModel()
            {
                Id = s.StudentId,
                FirstName = s.FirstName,
                LastName = s.LastName,
                Address = s.StudentAddress == null ? null : new AddressViewModel()
                {
                    StudentId = s.StudentAddress.StudentId,
                    Address1 = s.StudentAddress.Address1,
                    Address2 = s.StudentAddress.Address2,
                    City = s.StudentAddress.City,
                    State = s.StudentAddress.State
                }
            }).ToList<StudentViewModel>();
        }


        if (students.Count == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(students);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume AddressViewModel is a struct? It can’t be null since it’s a value type

Comment: Sami makes a good point; is StudentViewModel.Address property a struct or class type?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that Entity Framework can't translate that linq query to SQL. You should pull back the data first and then build your List. You can do it manually, or use AutoMapper. Here's a really trivial example of how to build it out manually (I would suggest you look into [Automapper](https://automapper.org/):

```
IList<StudentViewModel> vm = new List<StudentViewModel>();
using (var ctx = new StudentDBEntities())
{
    var students = ctx.Students.Include("StudentAddress");
    foreach (var student in students)
    {
        var s = new StudentViewModel
        {
            Id = student.StudentId,
            FirstName = student.FirstName,
            LastName = student.LastName,
        };

        if(student.StudentAddress != null)
        {
            s.Address = new AddressViewModel
            {
                StudentId = student.StudentAddress.StudentId,
                Address1 = student.StudentAddress.Address1,
                Address2 = student.StudentAddress.Address2,
                City = student.StudentAddress.City,
                State = student.StudentAddress.State
             };
        });

        vm.Add(s);
    }
}


if (!vm.Any())
{
   return NotFound();
}

return Ok(vm);
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all,I think you need to write 
{return new oK(students)}.
if "ok" is a class

Comment: `Ok()` is an [inherited method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.ok?view=aspnetcore-2.2)  off the controller class.  (the downvote wasn't from me either )